# Solving the functional equation $f: (0,+\infty) \to (0, +\infty):$ $f(x) = f(f(f(x))+y) + f(xf(y))\times f(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

A problem appeared in USAMO $2022$. Solve the functional equation $f: (0,+\infty) \to (0, +\infty):$

$$f(x) = f(f(f(x))+y) + f(xf(y))\times f(x+y)$$

I tried putting $x=1$,$y=1$ alternatively, using differentiation is also not proving to be helpful so what other methods can be applied?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: partial diff wrt y is zero

Comment: If there's no regularity assumption then you can't differentiate anyway.

Comment: Found a [thread about this problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h2808852p24774907) on AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

We claim that the only solution is $\forall x, f(x) = c/x$ for any $c > 0$. This clearly satisfy the conditions. Now, we shall prove that this is the only solution.

Let $f_{(n)}$ denote $f(x)$ iterated $n$ times and $P(x, y)$ denote the given statement.

##### Claim: Let $Q(a, b)$ denote the statement $f (a) ≥ f (b) \implies f (f (b)) ≥ a$. Then, $Q$ must be true.

Proof: Suppose by contradiction that $a > f (f (b))$. Then, consider $P (b, a − f (f (b)))$ to get a contradiction.

##### Claim: Any function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ obeying statement $Q$ satisfies $f_{(2)}(x) = f_{(4)}(x)$.

Proof: From $Q(t, t)$ we get $f_{(2)}(t) ≥ t$ for all $t > 0$.
So this already implies $f_{(4)}(x) ≥ f_{(2)}(x)$ by choosing $t = f_{(2)}(x)$. It also gives $f (x) ≤ f_{(3)}(x) ≤f_{(5)}(x)$ by choosing $t = f (x)$, $t = f_{(3)}(x)$.
Then $Q(f_{(4)}(x), x)$ is valid and gives $f_{(2)}(x) ≥ f_{(4)}(x)$, as needed.

##### Claim: $f(x)$ is injective.

Proof: Suppose $f (u) = f (v)$ for some $u > v$. From $Q(u, v)$ and $Q(v, u)$ we have $f_{(2)}(v) ≥ u$ and $f_{(2)}(u) ≥ v$. Note that for all $x > 0$ we have statements:

$$P (f_{(2)}(x), u) \implies f_{(3)}(x) = f (x + u) + f (xf (u))f (x + u) = (1 + f (xf (u)))f (x + u) \\
P (f_{(2)}(x), v) \implies f_{(3)}(x) = f (x + v) + f (xf (v))f (x + v) = (1 + f (xf (v)))f (x + v)$$
It follows that $f (x + u) = f (x + v)$ for all $x > 0$.
This means that $f$ is periodic with period $T = u − v > 0$. However, this is incompatible with $Q$, because we would have $Q(1 + nT, 1)$ for all positive integers $n$, which is obviously
absurd.

Since $f$ is injective, we obtain that $f_{(2)}(x) = x$. Thus $P (x, y)$ now becomes the statement
$f (x) = f (x + y)[1 + f (xf (y))]$

In particular
$P (1, y) \implies f (1 + y) = \frac{f (1)}{1+y}$
so $f$ is determined on inputs greater than $1$. Finally, if $a, b > 1$ we get
$P (a, b) \implies \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{a + b}[1 + f( \frac{a}{b} f (1))]$
which is enough to determine f on all inputs, by varying $(a, b)$.

Source: [Evan Chen](https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/USAMO-2022-notes.pdf). Sorry, I typed this in a rush, so please comment if there are any errors.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the source you used? https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/USAMO-2022-notes.pdf

Comment: Why get rid of "Source: Evan Chen"? It can be fine to retranscribe someone's solution as long as you give proper credit you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.